# What is the "keyID" when using APNs push service

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Usually there are 3 info I need to provide, to use Apple APNs: `key, keyId, teamId`, like [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications).

I understand `key` (pem file location) and `teamId`, but where do I find `keyId`? Is this somewhere in https://developer.apple.com ? Is this the bundle ID?

[image]

Answer (score 42):

```
key: 'apns.p8',   // Path to the key p8 file
keyId: 'ABCDE12345', // The Key ID of the p8 file (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/)
teamId: 'ABCDE12345', // The Team ID of your Apple Developer Account (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/)
```

You can find more on : https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/

Comment: Thanks, useful tutorial, any idea how should I change configuration not to get 403 error when sending notification to APNs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653808/invalidprovidertoken-403-response

Comment: @János The APN 403 is somewhat ambiguous. I'm on the same wild goose chase myself. Best way to find the solution is just keep trying new things until you figure it out. If I find a solution before you do I'll post back here.

Comment: @DheerajSingh Excellent detail by the way. Thanks for posting links to where I could find ID info. +1

Comment: this link is not valid now i think. https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/key . Instead the @kelin ' s link seems right https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey

Comment: @webenformasyon Yeah the link has updated, thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer.

Comment: @webenformasyo https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey also not working. It is redirect to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Comment: this no longer works in 2020, with Apple now downloading .cer file and having no way to see the key ID.

Answer (score 10):

If one don't have Key ID at `https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey`, he or she can follow this steps to create it:

1) Go to [Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account) aka Member Center > Certificates, IDs & Profiles > Keys / All > press the "+"
[image]

2) Enter Name and check APNs. The key is the same among your apps, so don't add app name to the key name. Click Confirm.
[image]

3) Download the key and be careful with it. Here you can see the Key ID (kid) value.
[image]

Comment: developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey also not working. It is redirect to developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Answer (score 10):

Key ID can also be derived from the name of the file for the key.
Your file with the key will probably be named something like: 
AuthKey_ABC1DEF11G.p8, so ABC1DEF11G is the key ID.

Team ID can be found on the Apple account webpage (upper right corner).