# InvalidProviderToken (403) response

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, openshift, node-apn

`node-apn` receive `InvalidProviderToken (403) response` error from APNs. What need I change in configuration to send push message?

Apple says: `APNs supports only provider authentication tokens that are signed with the ES256 algorithm. Unsecured JWTs, or JWTs signed with other algorithms, are rejected, and your provider server receives the InvalidProviderToken (403) response.`

Used this tutorial: https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/

Comment: wrong teamid  caused it

Comment: Best to add this as an answer and then accept it

Comment: FYI János found that out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621097/what-is-the-keyid-when-using-apns-push-service