# iOS Push Notifications keyId

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm having trouble figuring out what the `keyId` is for iOS Push Notifications.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621097/what-is-the-keyid-when-using-apns-push-service) question but it seems a bit out of date. Apple doesn't seem to give out `.p8` files for development anymore and they don't mention the `keyId` when downloading.

Also, I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn) library to send the notifications.

Any ideas where to find this?

**Edit:**

[image]

Above is the screen I get when trying to get the `.p8` file from Apple. When clicking download it gives me a `.cer` file with no `keyId`.

Comment: The detail is on [the site](https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/) linked to in the answer to question you referenced; When you generate the p8 file on the Apple developer portal the key id is shown on screen.  I don't know why you say the linked question is out of date, it is 100% correct

Comment: @Paulw11 Just added a screenshot of what I get from Apple after choosing `APNs Auth Key` and following the steps as discussed on the site you linked above.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm also getting an error `VError: Failed to generate token: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` but I'm guessing once I solve this issue that error will be fixed.

Comment: You aren't generating the right thing.  You need to select "Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production)", under "production", then you will get a screen with the key id and a link to the p8 file.  You know you have the right option when it doesn't ask you to upload a certificate signing request and the expiration is "never"

Answer (score -1):

Check [How to use Apple's new .p8 certificate for APNs in firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672297/how-to-use-apples-new-p8-certificate-for-apns-in-firebase-console)

To generate `.p8` file, you need to select "Apple Push Notification Authentication key (Sandbox and Production)" under production section.